# threeparttable caption width destroyed by floatrow package

Tags: floats, captions, threeparttable, floatrow

When I use the `floatrow` package, `threeparttable`'s ability to change the caption width to fit the table seems to be lost. The first image shows what I expect:

[image: This is the behavior I want]

But this behaviour is lost with `floatrow`.

[image: It is lost with floatrow]

Any ideas?

MWE below.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=sc]{caption}
%%% comment the next two lines out and the caption width wortks
\usepackage{floatrow}  % this package removes tpt caption width
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
%%%
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htb]   %% add [htb] here for better
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{Some caption to demonstrate my issue}
            \begin{tabular}{lll}
                Letter & Number & Number\\
                \hline
                Alpha & 123 & 10\\
                Beta & 246 & 100\\
                Delta & 369 & 1000\\
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item[] Some notes, these seem to be working
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are floatroaw and KOMA compatible?  KOMA replaces \caption and floatrow replaces \@makecaption.

Comment: @JohnKormylo the issue persists if I change the class to article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the floatrow syntax. I took the opportunity to slightly improve the table with the rules from `booktabs`, which have some vertical padding and make tables look less tight.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%{scrartcl}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=sc]{caption}
%%% comment the next two lines out and the caption width wortks
\usepackage{floatrow} % this package removes tpt caption width
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb] %% add [htb] here for better
   \ttabbox{\caption{Some caption to demonstrate my issue}}{\begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{lll}
                Letter & Number & Number\\
               \midrule
                Alpha & 123 & 10\\
                Beta & 246 & 100\\
                Delta & 369 & 1000\\
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item[]\hskip-0.25em Some notes, these seem to be working
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]