# Wide threeparttables that stretch out into the outer margin in two-sided memoir document

Tags: memoir, threeparttable, floatrow, tabulary

I have a `threeparttable` in a `memoir` document that I would like to at most stretch from the text block's inner margin to the outer margin of the margin notes. I would further like for the table to start at the inner margin on odd numbered pages and end at the inner margin on odd numbered pages.

I thought that combination of `tabulary` and `floatrow` would give me this and thusly I concocted the following, which sadly does **not at all** what I want. It is clear that the tables do not start where I would like them to. I suspect that the width is also wrong. And, perhaps least apparent, the caption of the second table does not appear to have the same width as its table.

What should I be doing instead? I have tried reading the `floatrow` documentation, but it is pretty quiet on the subject.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\let\newfloat\undefined% [Fix error loading `floatrow` with `memoir`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246918/71332)
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\maxfloatwidth}
\setlength{\maxfloatwidth}{\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}% Ought to be the length from the text block's inner margin to the outer margin of the margin notes
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
  \Blindtext[3]
  \thisfloatsetup{margins=hangoutside}
  \begin{table}[t]
    \begin{floatrow}
      \ttabbox{\caption{A table heading that goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on}}{\begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabulary}{\maxfloatwidth}{@{} L c c c @{}}
          \toprule
          A & B & C & D \tabularnewline
          \midrule
          a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a & 123 & 456 & 789 \tabularnewline
          a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a & 123 & 456 & 789 \tabularnewline
          \bottomrule
        \end{tabulary}
        \begin{tablenotes}
          \item[a] \blindtext
        \end{tablenotes}
      \end{threeparttable}}
    \end{floatrow}
  \end{table}
  \Blindtext[5]
  \thisfloatsetup{margins=hangoutside}
  \begin{table}[t]
    \begin{floatrow}
      \ttabbox{\caption{A table heading that goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on}}{\begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabulary}{1.2\linewidth}{@{} L c c c @{}}
          \toprule
          A & B & C & D \tabularnewline
          \midrule
          a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a & 123 & 456 & 789 \tabularnewline
          a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a & 123 & 456 & 789 \tabularnewline
          \bottomrule
        \end{tabulary}
        \begin{tablenotes}
          \item[a] \blindtext
        \end{tablenotes}
      \end{threeparttable}}
    \end{floatrow}
  \end{table}
  \Blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

[image: Table on even-numbered page]

[image: Table on odd-numbered page]

Comment: Am I correct that you want it to go into the outer margin? Tthen `memoir`'s own `adjustwidth` would be enough.

Comment: @daleif You are correct :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `adjustwidth*`. Note there is no need to use the `calc` package anymore. And `memoir` has something similar to `showframe` build in.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\newlength{\maxfloatwidth}
\setlength{\maxfloatwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}% 
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{showlocs} % similar to showframe

%\strictpagecheck

\begin{document}
  \Blindtext[3]
  \begin{table}[t]
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{0pt}{\dimexpr-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth\relax}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{A table heading that goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on}
        \begin{tabulary}{\maxfloatwidth}{@{} L c c c @{}}
          \toprule A & B & C & D \tabularnewline \midrule a a a a a a
          a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
          a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a & 123 & 456
          & 789 \tabularnewline a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
          a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
          a a a a a a a a a a a & 123 & 456 & 789 \tabularnewline
          \bottomrule
        \end{tabulary}
        \begin{tablenotes}
          \item[a] \blindtext
        \end{tablenotes}
      \end{threeparttable}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
  \end{table}
  \Blindtext[5]
  \begin{table}[t]
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{0pt}{\dimexpr-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth\relax}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{A table heading that goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on}
        \begin{tabulary}{\maxfloatwidth}{@{} L c c c @{}}
          \toprule A & B & C & D \tabularnewline \midrule a a a a a a
          a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
          a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a & 123 & 456
          & 789 \tabularnewline a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
          a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
          a a a a a a a a a a a & 123 & 456 & 789 \tabularnewline
          \bottomrule
        \end{tabulary}
        \begin{tablenotes}
          \item[a] \blindtext
        \end{tablenotes}
      \end{threeparttable}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
  \end{table}
  \Blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Strange. Even though the `adjustwidth*` environment is used, the floats extend into the right margin irrespective of its placed on an odd or even page. (This is clearer with `showframe` :-D)

Comment: See the commented line

Comment: Wohoo! Thanks :-) But why did you comment it in the first place…?

Comment: My only complaint is that it isn't responsive for even numbered pages. It works when the table is really `\maxfloatwidth` wide, but my intention was that that was just a maximum. When the table is narrower than that, then the table is too far to the left. That is, it start at the outer margin of the margin notes and ends before the inner margin of the text block, whereas I'm after the opposite.

Comment: That was not specified. Add `\ifoddpage\raggedright\else\raggedleft\fi` as the first thing inside the `adjustwidth`

Comment: Thanks! I thought that it was implied when I specified how long the width should be "at most". I guess that I should've added fewer a's in the leftmost cells... But then there probably would've been objections for why I couldn't just use a plain old `tabular` instead of `tabulary`. It seems I can never be clear enough when I post questions involving `tabulary`...

Answer (score 1):

Quite similar to nice @daleif answer (+1), but instead of `threeparttable` and `tabulary` packages I would rather use `talltblr` of `tabularray` package. Using it the table code is shorter and table looks a wee bit nicer:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{showlocs} % similar to showframe
\strictpagecheck     % <---

\begin{document}
\chapter{Very important chapter}
  \lipsum[1-3]
\section{Section with wide table}
\lipsum[4]
  
  \begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{0pt}{-\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
    \begin{talltblr}[
    caption = {A table heading that goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on},
      label = {tab:talltblr},
    note{a} = {\lipsum[66]},
                    ]{colspec = {@{} X[j] c c c @{}}}
          \toprule 
    A   & B     & C     & D     \\
          \midrule
    a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a 
        & 123   & 456   & 789   \\
    a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a 
        & 123   & 456   & 789   \\
          \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! (+1) But surely `tabularray` hasn’t yet been updated so that it can replace `tabulary`? https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/discussions/397

Comment: @FredrikP, I don't see, why in your case the `tabulary` should be used. The same result you get with  `tabularx` table or as I suggested by temporary version of the `tabularray` package.  As package author ones noted, next version of package will appear soon. It may introduce support "tabulary" (which you can already imitate as is shown in link you provide).

Comment: The table in the example is not the one that I have in my actual document :-) I guess that I should’ve added fewer a’s in the leftmost cells… Also, I’ve tried the code that allegedly imitates `tabulary`. It doesn’t. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683538/replicate-tabularys-l-column-with-tabularray

Comment: @FredrikP, I said that  in your particular case shown in you question there is no difference between `tabulary` and `tabularx` table. . For other tables we haven't any information here. As I see, You got nice solution with use of `tabulary` package. Stick with it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why using `floatrow`. If your aim is that such big floats on odd numbered pages stick on the right and the opposite on even numbered pages, you can use `adjustwidth` (that's built-in in `memoir`).

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\Blindtext[3]

\begin{table}[htp]
\checkoddpage

\begin{adjustwidth}
  {-\ifoddpage 0pt\else\dimeval{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}\fi}
  {-\ifoddpage\dimeval{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}\else 0pt\fi}

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{A table heading that goes on and on and on and on 
and on and on and on and on and on and on}

\begin{tabularx}{\dimeval{\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}}{@{} X c c c @{}}
  \toprule
  A & B & C & D \tabularnewline
  \midrule
  a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
  a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a & 123 & 456 & 789 \tabularnewline
  a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
  a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a & 123 & 456 & 789 \tabularnewline
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] \blindtext
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{adjustwidth}

\end{table}

\Blindtext[5]

\begin{table}[htp]
\checkoddpage

\begin{adjustwidth}
  {-\ifoddpage 0pt\else\dimeval{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}\fi}
  {-\ifoddpage\dimeval{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}\else 0pt\fi}

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{A table heading that goes on and on and on and on 
and on and on and on and on and on and on}

\begin{tabularx}{\dimeval{\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}}{@{} X c c c @{}}
  \toprule
  A & B & C & D \tabularnewline
  \midrule
  a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
  a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a & 123 & 456 & 789 \tabularnewline
  a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
  a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a & 123 & 456 & 789 \tabularnewline
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] \blindtext
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{adjustwidth}

\end{table}

\Blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

No need for `tabulary` either.

Comment: In my actual document, I use `floatrow` to place the captions of tables above the figure (and of figures below) and also to make the font in the table body sans serif. (This [disrupts `threeparttable`'s ability to make the caption as wide as the table body](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534196/threeparttable-caption-width-destroyed-by-floatrow-package).) I use `tabulary` for the cases where the table width is less than my specified maximum. I guess that I could decide whether to use `tabularx` or `tabular` on a case by case basis. But it would be nice if it could be avoided.